# Docker creating hundreds of volumes that cannot be pruned

Tags: docker, docker-volume, diskspace

We have an Ubuntu server that runs a few test environments under Docker. The system ran out of space today, and I eventually found that `/var/lib/docker` had grown to 826 GB with `/var/lib/docker/volumes` alone making 600 GB thereof.

Turns out that docker has created over 1,300 volumes:

```
$ docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          12        12        9.271GB   447.8MB (4%)
Containers      12        10        405.9MB   62.84MB (15%)
Local Volumes   1307      8         634.8GB   630.8GB (99%)
Build Cache     3586      0         19.05GB   19.05GB
```

I tried `docker volume prune` (and also with force-pruning images and containers before that), but that removed only a handful volumes.

We have another server with the same test environments under Docker, and it's looks totally different (i.e. normal) with only 9 volumes:

```
$ docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          13        13        10.07GB   447.8MB (4%)
Containers      14        10        312.2MB   111.7MB (35%)
Local Volumes   9         9         5.212GB   0B (0%)
Build Cache     0         0         0B        0B
```

If I check one of these volumes to find out which contain er or image it belongs to, I get nothing:

```
$ docker ps -a --filter volume=ff17641242297f3f9f3a63b2c328168f93c514e6e41cc3ed19bfbcb192acb5c7
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
```

The I tried a more radical solution:

```
$ docker system prune -a -f
```

It deleted a lot of build cache objects (21 GB in total), but no volumes.

How can it be that Docker has created 1,300 volumes that cannot be pruned? And what can I do to fix that?

---

Note that I found [Why did my docker volume run out of disk space?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76704770/docker-creating-hundreds-of-volumes-that-cannot-be-pruned), but the solutions given in the answers there do not work, so I assume my problem is a different one.

Comment: This seems to be more of an administration question than a programming question.  Do you have a [mcve] or any code that shows what might be creating the volumes?

Comment: It now seems to be a problem within docker itself. I was just creating images and containers regularly over months, so hard to tell a specific code.

Comment: Have you tried `docker volume prune -a`. Without a [mcve], this is just a random guess.

Comment: @BMitch Yes, I did. I’m afraid I don’t know how to reproduce the issue, so can’t provide an example. Maybe this question should be relocated to superuser?

Comment: Just to add a comment to this by running your images with the `--rm` option, i.e. `docker run --rm ...`, this will remove the container AND the volume after the container exits (assuming the volume is not a named volume)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This command eventually did it:

```
docker volume rm $(docker volume ls -q --filter dangling=true)
```

According to the docs, `docker volume prune -f` should actually do the job, but it didn't. According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40654726/4850949), the above is "the old way" to do it, but obviously, it is the way it actually works, too.